# Django return a single record as JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, json

I created a form for adding notes about a customer in our web admin. I am using jQuery and Ajax to submit the for. I would like the Django view to return the newly added note/record so I can append it to the customer notes table. My Ajax send is working, and the note is being saved, I just can't display the result.

I have tried the following 3 lines (separately):

```
serializers.serialize("json", Note.objects.get(id=new_note.id))
serializers.serialize("json", new_note)
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(new_note), mimetype='application/javascript')
```

The first 2 each produce:

```
'Note' object is not iterable
```

And the 3rd one gave me:

```
<Note: Note object> is not JSON serializable
```

I don't actually care in which format I return the object, as long as I can receive and display each field of the record using jQuery.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#topics-serialization):

> The arguments to the serialize function are the format to serialize the data to (see Serialization formats) and a QuerySet to serialize.

Use `filter()` instead of `get()`.

Comment: Thanks. I read the docs and saw that it had to be a query set, I didn't realize that it would work with .filter().

Comment: I really think neoprolog's answer is exactly what you are looking for in this case. Not everyone has the query set they want to use at the moment they want to serialize.

Answer (score 10):

Use:

```
serializers.serialize("json", [new_note])
```

(attention to square brackets around query object)