# Converting only one entry of django model object to json

Tags: django, json, django-models

I have a **model Y** with 3 fields. In this model Y, I have 5 entries.

I know that I can use:

```
from django.core import serializers

def aMethodThatReturnsJson():
    return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize("json", Y.objects.all()))
```

This returns a proper json response.

But when I change the method to return only 1 row from the model, like below, I get Model Y is not iterable error:

```
def returnOnlyOneRow():
    return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize("json", Y.objects.get(pk=1)))
```

Why does this not return a proper json object? What is the correct way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django return a single record as JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255910/django-return-a-single-record-as-json)

Comment: Thanks. That answered my question. In my half-a-day of searches, that answer somehow never showed up. :-(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is the way to do it:

```
from django.core import serializers

def return_only_one_row():
    return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize("json", Y.objects.filter(pk=1)))
```

Using `filter()` instead of `get()` returns the proper JSON response.

Another way to do it would be to use Python lists. You can wrap the query in `[ ]` to turn the resulting response to a list and then serialize it to JSON. Example follows:

```
def return_only_one_row():
    return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize("json", [Y.objects.get(pk=1)]))
```

Comment: Great answer, was looking for a way to serialize just ONE returned object. This solved it.